# ng-metadata @Directive: how to set input value?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I've got a pretty simple directive, which should update the input value on blur.

The blur handler is getting called, but I can't manage to set the input value.

```
import {NgModel} from 'ng-metadata/common';
import {Directive, Inject, Self, HostListener} from 'ng-metadata/core';

@Directive({
  selector: 'foo'
})
export class FooDirective {
  constructor(
    private @Self() ngModel: NgModel,
    private @Inject('$element') $element: ng.IAugmentedJQuery
  ) {}

  @HostListener('blur')
  onBlur() {
    this.ngModel.$viewValue = "FOO";
    this.ngModel.$modelValue = "FOO";
    this.ngModel.$setViewValue("FOO");
    this.ngModel.$commitViewValue();
    // I guess, I just need one of these, but none did work
  }
}
```

**HTML Code:**

```
<input type="text" foo ng-model="$ctrl.abc"></input>
```

---

I can read the current value using `console.log(this.ngModel.$modelValue)`, but I'm not able to set a new value.

---

What did i miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it!

It's as simple as:

```
this.ngModel.$setViewValue("FOO");
this.ngModel.$render();
```